# Declaring the Unix flavour in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, unix

How do I declare in C/C++ that the code that is written is to be built in either HP-UX or Solaris or AIX?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found that, a good way to figure this king of question, is, at least with gcc, to have this makefile:

```
defs:
    g++ -E -dM - < /dev/null
```

then, :

```
$ make defs
```

should output all the definitions you have available.

So:

```
$ make defs | grep -i AIX
$ make defs | grep -i HP
```

should give you the answer. Example for Linux:

```
$ make defs | grep -i LINUX
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define linux 1
```

Once you found the define you are looking for, you type at the beginning of your code:

```
#if !(defined(HP_DEFINE) || defined(AIX_DEFINE) || defined(SOLARIS_DEFINE))
#  error This file cannot be compiled for your plateform
#endif
```

Comment: Very cool - nice to learn something new today.  It should be noted that not all target system (i.e. embedded systems) have custom predefined macros for gcc.  Especially if you are just using a generic CPU-specific gcc build (targeting a processor rather than a system) to generate code.  In this case, you need to create your own predefined macro with the -D option.

Answer (score 4):

How about a macro passed to the compiler ?

`i.e. gcc -Dmacro[=defn]`

Then test for the macro in your code with a simple `#ifdef` of `#if` (if you've given it a value). There may already be a predefined macro for your target platform as well.

---

[EDIT: Put some of my comments here in my answer that explain how `-D` works]

`-Dmacro[=defn]` on the command line for the compiler is the same as having `#define macro defn` in the code.  You expand it out like this: `-Dfoo=bar` is equivalent to `#define foo bar`.  Also, the definition is optional so `-Dfoo` is equivalent to `#define foo`.

Comment: could you please explain about this `-D`

Comment: `-Dmacro[=defn]` on the command line for the compiler is the same as having `#define macro defn` in the code.

Comment: You expand it out btw... like this: `-Dfoo=bar` is equivalent to `#define foo bar`.

Comment: This is actually very common (we use the Unreal Engine for our game and this is how they target platforms -- well they use the IDE-integration to set up predefinitions but this is what actually gets passed on the command line).  It's pretty much the only way to do it if your compiler doesn't have the appropriate predefinitions for your target platform.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful about how you handle this.  You should identify the features of the O/S that you want to use by feature, not by O/S, and write your code accordingly.  Then, in one header, you can identify which of the features are available on the O/S that you are compiling on.  This is the technique used by autoconf, and even if you do not use autoconf itself, the technique it espouses is better than the platform-based technique.  Remember, the features found on one O/S often migrate and become available on others too, so if you work by features, you can adapt to the future more easily than if you work solely on the O/S.

You also have to write your code appropriately, and portably.  Isolate the O/S dependencies in separate files whenever possible, and code to an abstract O/S interface that does what you need.  Taken to an extreme, you end up with a Java JVM; you don't need to go that far, but you can obviate most of the problems.

Take a look at portable libraries like the Apache Portable Runtime (APR) library.

And write your code along the lines of:

```
#ifdef HAVE_PWRITE
...code using pread() and pwrite()...
#else
...code using plain old read() and write()...
#endif
```

This is a grossly over-simplified example - there could be a number of fallbacks before you use plain read() and write().  Nevertheless, this is the concept used in the most portable code - things like GCC and Apache and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a less convoluted solution that some of those suggested is to consult [Pre-defined C/C++ Compiler Macros](http://predef.sourceforge.net/).  This site provides an extensive list of compiler macros for a large number of compiler/OS/Architecture combinations.